# C# Updating Environment Variable - SendMessageTimeout

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an system environment variable, I note for the change to be reflected I've got to do a SendMessageTimeout to update the windows.

I can get it to run, and return a 0 result, but the environment variable is not ever actually updated.

```
[Flags]
public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
{
    SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
    SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
    SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
IntPtr hWnd,
uint Msg,
UIntPtr wParam,
IntPtr lParam,
SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags,
uint uTimeout,
out UIntPtr lpdwResult);


string reg_subkey = "Test1";
string reg_name = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";
Registry.SetValue(reg_name, reg_subkey, "testing", RegistryValueKind.String);

IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
const uint WM_WININICHANGE = 0x001A;
const uint WM_SETTINGCHANGE = WM_WININICHANGE;
const int MSG_TIMEOUT = 15000;
UIntPtr RESULT;

string ENVIRONMENT = "Environment";

SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ENVIRONMENT), SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, MSG_TIMEOUT, out RESULT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`. This calls `SendMessageTimeout` internally.

Comment: Yes, this is a much simpler approach.

Comment: It is a much simpler approach, except if you are attempting to set the environment variable in the "user" space.  The SendMessageTimeout blocks on the message returning (or until the timeout occurs).  This can mean that it takes several seconds per variable to set... if you have multiple variables, it takes unacceptably long.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` function followed by the `SendMessageTimeout`, this has worked in my teams testing with updating the PATH variable in the machine context. We also found to the contrary of documentation that `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` only works by itself when creating a new variable. We are testing in a scenario where the parent process must get the updated PATH variable.